# Mac OS X socket timeout

Tags: java, macos, sockets, timeout

I have a weird problem in my OS X (Yosemite) machine: it seems that the network communication is slower than in other Windows machines of the same network, and the timeout seems shorter.

When I try to run our Java application, each transaction that is longer than 15s returns:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Operation timed out
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:876)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
    at dome.dbComponents.dataModels.rowSet.StatementStatus.executeQuery(StatementStatus.java:71)
    at com.dome.dCell.common.services.enterprise.types.Infusr.loadSQLFieldList(Infusr.java:976)
    at dome.util.xml.converter.typeSQLManager.ThreadLoadSqlField.run(ThreadLoadSqlField.java:103)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) 
INFO  [28 Aug 2015 14:35:32,427] DomeEnterpriseService.loadAll(true) executed in 19724 ms
```

The timeout occurs when our Enterprise Service takes more than 15s to load all the enterprises from the database (it's not a bad query, there's simply a lot of information to store in memory).

This is not likely related directly to our software configuration being incompatible with OS X. I tried to run the same application in a Windows 7 VM (with VirtualBox) on the same iMac, and the problem remains.

I checked the connection with the database machine (a Linux server), and everything seems fine.

I've also tried different configurations in `/etc/sysctl.conf` (`net.inet.tcp.msl`) but it doesn't seem to make a big difference. Also, I don't find anything like the `net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries` configuration of Linux, and maybe I'm googling the wrong keywords, but I don't find much about tweaking the timeout of OS X.

I don't recall having this problem before on this machine. I updated the JDK 1.7 to the last version (1.7.0_79), all the OS updates, nothing improves. 
We tried with different machines (Linux & Windows, it's the only Mac), and no one is able to reproduce this.

Any ideas?